# Xampp Virtual host, one website redirects to another

Tags: wordpress, apache, xampp, virtualhost

So, i am very new to this but here we go:

I wanted to set up a second WordPress website on my XAMPP install. It worked quite well, first set up a virtual host in the httpd-vhosts.conf file. i used the following code (yes, the websites are called testsite and testsite2 as 2 is just a copy of 1, and yes that was a bad idea)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80 



<VirtualHost *:80> 

DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/ 

ServerName localhost 

</VirtualHost> 



<VirtualHost *:80> 

DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/testsite/" 

ServerName Localhost/testsite/ 

<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/testsite/"> 

</Directory> 

</VirtualHost> 



<VirtualHost *:80> 

DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/testsite2/" 

ServerName Localhost/testsite2/ 

<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/testsite2/"> 

</Directory> 

</VirtualHost>
```

I then added the following code to my "hosts" file in windows:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost 

127.0.0.1       localhost/testsite 

127.0.0.1       localhost/testsite2
```

So, both websites are working. but then i notice that, when I try to access any page other than the home page, on my second website, it redirects me to the homepage of the first website.

I suspect it might have something to do with caching or with the -htaccess files as the one for website2 is the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteBase /testsite/blog/ 

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule . /testsite/blog/index.php [L] 

</IfModule> 


# END WordPress
```

and I'm pretty sure it shouldn't reference website 1.